# export org to pdf not working: PDF was not produced

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf, org-publish

installed emacs and Latex ()texlive and texlive-latex-extra) on ubuntu.
Exported an Org file to PDF with no success.

Exporting via org-export-dispatch  and selected **[l]** export to latex and **[O]** as PDF file and open Beamer. Tried [p] export to pdf too. To no avail.

message is : **"pdf was not produced. See "*Org PDF LaTEx Output*" for details"**

EXAMPLE ORG:

```
* BASH
** Find files older than.....
#+BEGIN_SRC bash find files older 1 day
find /path/to/folder/ -mtime +1
# and then delete -exec rm -rf {} \;
# 1 hour older
find /path/to/folder -mmin +59
#+END_SRC
```

This is my message buffer (actual file is much longer):

```
org-babel-exp process sql at position 33...
org-babel-exp process bash at position 370...
org-babel-exp process bash at position 460...

Wrote /home/joe/.emacs.d/.local/cache/undo-tree-hist/.!home!joe!Documents!org!snippets.org.~undo-tree~ [2 times]
Wrote /home/joe/Documents/org/.export/snippets.tex
"org/.export/snippets.tex" 73L, 2035C written
Processing LaTeX file /home/joe/org/.export/snippets.tex...
org-compile-file: File "/home/joe/org/.export/snippets.pdf" wasn’t produced.  See "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*" for details
```

Checked mentioned latex file:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `beamer.cls' not found.
```

so I tried to install beamer:

```
    sudo apt-get install latex-beamer
[sudo] password for joe: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package latex-beamer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'latex-beamer' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: As the message says: `See "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*" for details` - that's a buffer containing the LaTeX output (including the error messages that prevented the PDF from being produced). Switch to it with `C-x b` and see what went wrong.

Comment: In cases like this, it is also helpful to process the exported LaTex file: if your Org mode file is called `foo.org`, after the export there should be a `foo.tex` file in the same directory. Process that file with `pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex`.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `beamer.cls' not found.

Comment: sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-latex-recommended is already the newest version (2019.20190710-1)

Comment: Presumably your org file is a presentation and you are using `beamer` which you need to install. Try `sudo apt install texlive-beamer`.

Comment: unable to locate package texlive-beamer

Comment: I guess it's called `latex-beamer` in Debian/Ubuntu - you can search Google for these things.

Comment: You should add all the information from the comments to your question, so that it is self contained. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Package latex-beamer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: the beamer.cls file is part of texlive-latex-recommended, so I suspect it is already installed on your system. Can you show us a minimal org file that generates this problem, and tell us how you are trying to export it? The problem may be you have manually added the beamer class, and are using the regular pdf export, rather than the beamer-specific export options.

Comment: it fails with the most simple Org file. Attached an example to question

Comment: If that's your whole Org file, then @Tyler is right: it should have nothing to do with beamer. Can you add the TeX file that is produced to your question?

Comment: what keys/commands are you using to export the file?